# How to annotate strings in django objects

Tags: python, django

I want to concatinate first name + last name but i'm getting 0 as a value of full name

What I'm trying to do is this

```
Customer.objects.annotate(full_name=F('first_name') + F('last_name')).filter(full_name='Filan Fisteku')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat


ss = Customer.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')).filter(full_name='Filan Fisteku')
```